# The car is rolling or spinning?

Tags: grammar

I want to describe this video to my son with the most correct local speaker grammar.
Of course, I want to learn too.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YRxbXZ19ucw

So what statements can I use from the below? Video's description was "roll over".

**PHRASE 1**

"The car is spinning."

"The car is spinning around very fast."

"The car is rolling."

"The car is rolling over".

**PHRASE 2**

"The car is breaking apart"

"The car is getting destroyed"

"The car is breaking up"

"The car is broken now"

"The car is wrecked now"

"The car is completed crashed now"

How would you describe what's on the video if you are going to put short subtitles on it?

Thank you.

Comment: I've answered, but I suggest you edit your question down to avoid it being deleted. The first part about word-choice is focused enough. But the list of phrases and asking to check them is off-topic.

Comment: Aside: I wouldn't put subtitles to describe the obvious, but to *add* value. For example: "Oh no, he has braked too hard!" and "Can he get control back?" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a *car* "rolls", this usually means that it has flipped over onto its roof. This definition is specific to cars - in other contexts, rolling and spinning could mean the same thing. Cars can be engineered to incorporate a "[roll cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roll_cage)" which protects it should it flip over onto its roof.

A car "spinning" could mean skidding around to face the opposite direction. But if you said that the car flipped onto its roof and *then* began spinning, that could describe its perpetually flipping over and over.

Watching the video, the rolls tend to start very suddenly. I would probably use the word "flip" as this conveys it turning over and with speed.

I'm not going to sense-check each one of your listed phrases - that part of the question is a little off-topic as it doesn't have any focus or show any research. All I will say is that you can't have gradations of "crashed" - something either has crashed, or it hasn't. A crash is a collision, not a state of damage.

Comment: Thank you. Answer is very detailed.

Answer (score 1):

As the motion is spinning, rolling *and* flipping followed by an uncontrolled fall off a cliff, I would use the word **tumbling** to describe it.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tumble) has

> **tumble**
> *intransitive verb*
>
> **3** : to roll over and over, to and fro, or end over end
> **2b** : to turn end over end in falling or flight
> **1a** : to fall suddenly and helplessly

So I would say

> The car tumbled down the road and over a cliff.

Comment: Thank you, I would have checked this answer as well if given the chance to check two answers.